# How to integrate other template engines in mean.io in place of JADE

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to change template engine in [mean.io](http://mean.io) boilerplate. Its default is JADE. Can some one guide me how to change its template engine to ECTJS or HOGAN.JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Martin Genev piece about this here  - http://www.100percentjs.com/replacing-jade-with-hogan-in-an-express-js-app-the-mean-stack/